# How can I fix this RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, angular

i have an regEx like this:

```
/(url:\/\/.*\/.*\/.*[^:",])/
```

to match urls like this:

```
"url://address/abc/v1/folders/-K5da6uPz7OTMQrRPjQ6yALXXC1whG08BTgX5adQsLY"
```

However if I have two of these urls like that:

```
"url://address/abc/v1/folders/-123456789": "url://address/abc/v1/folders/-987654321"
```

the RegEx recognizes them as one and dont seperates them.

How can i write the RegEx that its seperates them as one and that it still works if they are not directly side by side?

Thank you!

Comment: can you split the string?

Comment: `java != javascript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use repeat matching a forward slash followed by matching any char except a forward slash or a whitespace to prevent overmatching.

```
url:\/\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+\/[^\s:"]+
```

- `url:\/\/` Match `ur://`
- `[^\/]+` Match 1+ times any char except `/`
- `(?:\/[^\/\s]+)+` Repeat 1+ times matching `/` and 1+ times any char except `/`
- `\/[^\s:"]+` Match the last `/` and use a character class excluding any of the listed characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EDntQJ/1)

If a single forward slash could also be matched, you could use a `*` instead of a `+` as a quantifier for the group:

```
url:\/\/[^\/]+(?:\/[^\/\s]+)*\/[^\s:"]+
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split()` function and store the resulting Strings into an array. Then you iterate and check each element to match your RegEx

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern

```
(url:\/\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+))
```

Here you have an example how it works

https://regex101.com/r/NQxKIc/2

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you want the quotes included

```
("url:\/\/[\S]+")
```

without

```
(url:\/\/[a-zA-z\d\/-]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Didn`t you miss one "/.*" in your expresion (?) I mean... you have 4 sections but this regex only match 3 subsections. There is a preview of your [regex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzkcD.png)

Answer (score 0):

the following regex will match both separately

`(url:\/\/[^ ":]*)`

- `url:\/\/` matches `url://`
- `[^ ":]*` matches 0 or more characters that are not a space, ' : ' or ' " '